# JSONObject is giving Error on WebSphere 6.1

Tags: java, json, jakarta-ee

I am using `Tomcat` 5 and `WebSphere` 6.1. `JSONObject` is giving a runtime error in like `***"java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.json.JSONObject"***` 
 and it's working fine in Tomcat.

I created a JSON object like below.

```
JSONObject json   = new JSONObject();
JSONArray  redClassList = new JSONArray();
JSONArray  whiteClassList = new JSONArray();
```

**Here is the log.**

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.json.JSONObject
    at com.util.ConfiguratorUtil.validateForm(ConfiguratorUtil.java:885)
    at com.util.ConfiguratorUtil.setdesiredQty(ConfiguratorUtil.java:855)
    at com.struts.actions.ConfiguratorAction.processAjax(ConfiguratorAction.java:133)
    ... 30 more
```

[image]

Comment: are you having the json jar in your classspath?

Comment: @SparkOn yes i have , it work fine with tomcat. when i try with webspear it gives error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Class NoClassDefFoundError](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/NoClassDefFoundError.html):

> Thrown if the Java Virtual Machine or a ClassLoader instance tries to
>   load in the definition of a class (as part of a normal method call or
>   as part of creating a new instance using the new expression) and no
>   definition of the class could be found.
>
> The searched-for class definition existed when the currently executing
>   class was compiled, but the definition can no longer be found.

It means it is not available in your classpath. It seems for Tomcat you have placed the required JAR file in Tomcat server classpath so Tomcat had no issues.

**Update:**

If your application a web application then you can place the JAR file at path:

```
<your_webapp>/WEB-INF/lib/
```

Placing the JAR file at this path will fix your issue as the JAR file will be available at run-time also.

Comment: same jar i use in both server.

Comment: @Jani Where you ae placing the Jar file?

Comment: @Jani The image shows that the JAR file is available only during compile time but not at run-time so that is the reason you are getting this exception (the definition of the exception also says the same thing). I have updated my post with what needs o be done to fix the issue, check it once.

Comment: Thank you for you help. but after i change class path i am getting other error. Please have a look on that.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25641993/java-lang-unsupportedclassversionerror-org-json-jsonobject-bad-major-version