# java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: (org/json/JSONObject) bad major version at offset=6

Tags: java, json, unsupported-class-version

In project i am using Websepear as server. After adding Json to my project i am getting below error.

```
---Original exception---
java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: (org/json/JSONObject) bad major version at offset=6
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassImpl(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:222)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:148)
    at com.ibm.ws.classloader.CompoundClassLoader._defineClass(CompoundClassLoader.java:526)
    at com.ibm.ws.classloader.CompoundClassLoader.findClass(CompoundClassLoader.java:477)
```

**Here is the Exception description .**

```
 Caused by: java.lang.LinkageError: LinkageError while defining class: org.json.JSONObject
    Could not be defined due to: (org/json/JSONObject) bad major version at offset=6
    This is often caused by having a class defined at multiple
    locations within the classloader hierarchy.  Other potential causes
    include compiling against an older or newer version of the class
    that has an incompatible method signature.
    Dumping the current context classloader hierarchy:
        ==> indicates defining classloader
    ==>[0]
```

**NOTE:-**
I built and run my project on java 6

Comment: What Java version was the library provided by the server built with?

Comment: @Thomas library provided Java6.

Comment: Another hint is given by the description: did you check there is only one jar within your application (or maybe even within the server) that contains this class?

Comment: @Thomas As i mention after adding json to project i am getting that error so i don't think JSONObject is duplicate in any other jar.

Comment: Well, you added it to your application, I guess. But that doesn't mean that there is not already a library provided by the server. Anyways, you might want to double check the Java version the library was built with as well as the existence of another conflicting library. Additionally you might want to state which library you added and the exact version you used. Otherwise it's still guesswork.

Comment: In your previous post you mentioned that you use WebSphere 6.1. That server runs on top of Java 5, so if you want to use JSON in your project running on WAS 6.1 you should find a library compiled with Java 5.

Answer (score 0):

As your application is deployed on server, please check on which version of Java the server is running. I guess the Server is running on lower version of Java where as your project is built on Java-6.

Comment: Thank you for your valuable comments but can u please describe why it for only JSONObject. this project work fine with out JSONObject. 
It's very helpful if you describe more on this.

Comment: it depends on how many jars you have in classpath, as per your earlier question it looks like you have only json.jar other than websphere specific jar in classpath and you are facing issue with this jar.Running new java code on old JVM will result in errors.

Answer (score 0):

Try to increase the compilation level and use a compatible JRE